# PHP using &lt; and &gt; in place of < and >

Tags: php

I'm following an [online PHP tutorial](http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/creating-your-first-php-application-part-2/) which uses `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` in the PHP code.  For example:

```
&lt;?php

class User {
function __construct($data) {
    $this-&gt;id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : "";
    $this-&gt;username = (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : "";
    $this-&gt;hashedPassword = (isset($data['password'])) ? $data['password'] : "";
    $this-&gt;email = (isset($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : "";
    $this-&gt;joinDate = (isset($data['join_date'])) ? $data['join_date'] : "";
}
```

Is there a reason this is being done or is the formatting on the tutorial website causing it to display like that?

i.e. should I actually be using `&lt;` and `&gt;` in my .php files?

Comment: No, that's a code formatting/output problem of that blog only.

Comment: Looks like that tut is using a plugin that borked the code.

Comment: Is this displaying as the escaped character or as the `<` character when you visit the page

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It's a perfectly legitimate question...  And why would anyone vote to close?

Comment: If you can get in touch with the blog's author, tell them their code renderer is broken. It will save someone else the same trouble later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is broken.  They are using something to format code in the tutorial, and it is double-escaping the code.  You don't need to worry about that.

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are entities that are used in HTML and XML documents.  They are not needed in your PHP code.  If you output HTML with your PHP code, then the HTML part you output should contain them if you wish your document to contain a `<` or `>`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a mistake in the blog's rendering.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to worry about in your php files. When accepting user input from something like a form, it is a security vulnerability to allow them to write in code which you will then save and/or display. Converting them to their html entity form ensures that they are not being used as actual code.

In xml, using `<` and `>` refers to xml tags, so to the html entities are used as to differentiate between and html and xml tag.